In monitor scenario of Apache IoTDB, how to calculate the average compression ratio?
I am now learning the monitor function and tool of Apache IoTDB. I noticed that here is a "average of compression ratio" indicator mentioned in the monitor configuration in IoTDB. One single point compression ratio is understandable, but I am confused on how to calculate this average compression ratio in this monitoring case?

The average compression ratio of Apache IoTDB can be calculated by ratio_sum / memtable_flush_time, which ratio_sum means sum of memtable compression ratios. The compression ratio statistics file (which you can find these parameter information) is in data/system/compression_ratio/Ratio-{ratio_sum}- directory of IoTDB.
